# adding properties together from list of objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Looking to see if there is a simpler way to achieve this. I would love if I could keep the `return` as a one-line LINQ expression. I want to grab the total number of hints used, which can be more than one.

```
public int hintsUsed
{
    get
    {
        int i = 0;
        questions.ForEach(q => i += q.hintsUsed);
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Sum` function

```
public int HintsUsed => questions.Sum(q => q.hintsUsed);
```

By using an expression bodied member (since C# 6.0), you can even get rid of the `get` and the `return` keywords plus a few braces.

The code above is equivalent to

```
public int HintsUsed
{
    get
    {
        return questions.Sum(q => q.hintsUsed);
    }
}
```

Most of the LINQ-to-Objects functionality is provided by the [Enumerable Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ahh perfect, thank you. Sometimes its difficult to search for these things because I'm not sure which words to use. I will definitely use this in the future.